# Método para calcular tempo de desenvolvimento do diagrama entidade-relacionamento

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Existe algum método para calcular o prazo de entrega do diagrama DER? Objetivo: fornecer para o cliente uma estimativa de tempo para concluir o diagrama DER de um projeto de desenvolvimento de software com 114 tabelas (nesta modelagem existe dois analistas Junior dando manutenção) relacionando de acordo com regra de negócio.

Comment: Cara, acho que isso entra mais em gestão de projetos né... Enfim, neste âmbito, eu usaria PERT. Você deveria questioná-los por 3 prazos. Otimista, mais provável e pessimista. Daí, consegue fazer o cálculo do Pert e ter uma idéia aproximada de quanto tempo tomará para fazer isso e qualquer outra coisa. Recomendo...

Comment: A resposta a essa pergunta é o ativo mais importante de qualquer empresa. Isso é calculado com base no histórico de eficiência dos profissionais da empresa, o nível de conhecimento e treinamento desses profissionais, a existência de métodos claros estabelecidos pela empresa etc. Enfim, saber quanto tempo vocês levam para fazer algo depende da observação dos fatores ambientais da sua empresa. Em muitas empresas, os profissionais assinam um termo de confidencialidade que os proíbe de divulgarem o esforço para desenvolver um ponto por função, por exemplo.

Comment: Se as tabelas já existem, então alguém já fez a modelagem de dados, pois primeiro se modela, independente do gerenciador de banco de dados, e depois se cria o banco de dados (onde ficam as tabelas etc).